# Rspec testing methods in transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I am trying to execute two things inside a transaction and I'm not sure how I should test it in rspec. My code looks something like this:

Implementation:

```
    def method
      begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          ...some implementation...
          model1.save!
          model2.save!
        end
      rescue => e
          exception_info = {:class => e.class, :message => e.message, :backtrace => e.backtrace}
          @logger.warn("Error. Rolling back.", :exception => exception_info)
      end
    end
```

Tests:

```
it "model1 object is not created if model2 fails to save" do
  Model1.any_instance.should_receive(:save).and_raise("model1 save error!!")
  method
  Model2.all.should == []
end

it "" do
  Model2.any_instance.should_receive(:save).and_raise("model2 save error!!")
  method
  Model1.all.should == []
end
```

I want both the models to be saved or none. My rspec tests check both the cases but I keep getting errors. If I add (:requires_new => true) to the transaction, it works. I thought it was meant for nested transactions, not something like this. Am I missing something?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: model2 gets created when model1 blows up (raises error)

Comment: Your tests will always fail as `Model.all` will return `[]` if there are no records.

Comment: Also, are you using the `database_cleaner` gem? That wraps everything in a transaction.

Comment: Yes, it was just pseudo code. My code is doing a lot more than that. I'll update the test. I am not using the database_cleaner gem.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord transactions only rollback if an exception is raised. Otherwise they persist whatever records were successfully created.

In your case, you want to use `save!` instead of `save` to interrupt the transaction. This will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception which you need to rescue and handle.

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    ...some implementation...
    model1.save!
    model2.save!
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
end
```

Comment: I have this, still doesn't work:
  rescue => e
        exception_info = {:class => e.class, :message => e.message, :backtrace => e.backtrace}
        @logger.warn("Error. Rolling back.", :exception => exception_info)

Comment: @AmirShadaabMohammed I forgot the bang version, did you add it?

Comment: @AmirShadaabMohammed: Have you tested the functionality in your console? Does it roll back if one model fails to save?

Comment: I figured out the problem, I'll be posting the solution soon